# A problem with the expectation of a Pareto

Tags: bayesian, pareto-distribution

My course notes (3rd-year module in Bayesian Statistics, unpublished) contain the following section.

> Assume we have data on the number of people queuing at an ATM at a specific hour for several
> randomly chosen days, and that we are interested in the mean time between two consecutive arrivals to the queue at some arbitrary point within this time.
>
> First, let $\textbf{x} = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ represent the observed data and assume these are a random sample from $\text{Po}(x_i\;|\;\lambda)$. We will use the conjugate prior $\text{Ga}(\lambda\;|\;a,b)$ to represent our prior knowledge, thus $$\pi(\lambda\;|\;\textbf{x})\propto\left[\lambda^se^{-n\lambda}\right]\times\left[\lambda^{a-1}e^{-b\lambda}\right]=\text{Ga}(\lambda\;|\;a^\ast,b^\ast),$$ where $a^\ast=a+s$ and $b^\ast=b+n$, with $s=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ a sufficient statistic for $x_i$.
>
> Using standard queuing theory, the time within two consecutive arrivals, $y$, is distributed
> $\text{Ex}(y\;|\;\lambda)$. Thus, the predictive distribution is $$f(y\;|\;\textbf{x})=\int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-y\lambda}\frac{(b^\ast)^{a^\ast}}{\Gamma(a^\ast)}\lambda^{a^\ast-1}e^{-\lambda b^\ast}\;\text{d}\lambda=\frac{a^\ast}{b^\ast}\left(1+\frac{y}{b^\ast}\right)^{-(a^\ast+1)}.$$ Finally, the expected predictive time between consecutive arrivals is $$\mathbb{E}[y\;|\;\textbf{x}]=\int_0^\infty y\frac{a^\ast}{b^\ast}\left(1+\frac{y}{b^\ast}\right)^{-(a^\ast+1)}\;\text{d}y=\frac{b^\ast}{a^\ast-1}.$$

But, by my reasoning, \begin{align}
& \begin{aligned} f(y\;|\;\textbf{x}) 
& = \frac{a^\ast}{b^\ast}\left(1+\frac{y}{b^\ast}\right)^{-(a^\ast+1)} \\
& = \frac{a^\ast b^{\ast a^\ast}}{(y+b^\ast)^{a^\ast+1}} \\
& = \text{Pa}(y+b^\ast\;|\;a^\ast,b^\ast) \end{aligned} \\[1em]
\therefore \hspace{1em} & \begin{aligned}[t] 
\mathbb{E}[y\;|\;\textbf{x}] 
& = \mathbb{E}[y+b^\ast\;|\;y\sim\text{Pa}(a^\ast,b^\ast)] \\
& = \mathbb{E}[y\;|\;y\sim\text{Pa}(a^\ast,b^\ast)] + b^\ast \\
& = \frac{a^\ast b^\ast}{a^\ast-1} + b^\ast \\
& = \frac{(2a^\ast-1)b^\ast}{a^\ast-1} \\
& \neq \frac{b^\ast}{a^\ast-1} \text{ (unless $a^\ast=1$)}.
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

What's gone wrong?

Comment: You haven't integrated correctly.  Use $$\int_0^\infty x(1+x)^{-(1+a)}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^a}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^{a+1}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{a-1}-\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{a(a-1)}.$$

Comment: @whuber Thanks, that's useful, but I didn't integrate; I used the linearity of the expectation operator with a formula for the expectation of a Pareto distribution that I got from a formula sheet. Could you point out the problem with that line of reasoning?

Comment: Compare your work with the correct result until you see a discrepancy: that will locate at least one error.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't even make sense of it, because your notation "Pa" is undefined. Although one would guess it is referring to a Pareto distribution, I am unable to see how that is directly related to an integral whose *lower limit is $1.$*  The details matter, *especially* the meanings of your parameters $a^*$ and $b^*.$ I therefore encourage you to write your steps in detail.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I intend Pa to mean a Pareto distribution. I took it from my formula sheet and assumed it was standard notation. From the wikipedia [article](https://tinyurl.com/yk7juhtf) on the Gamma distribution I assume $a$ and $b$ are shape and rate, and the course notes use $^\ast$ for posterior parameters, which here turn out to fit a Pa. My formula sheet gives $b^\ast$ (that is, the parameter in the second position, which it actually calls $\beta$) as the lower limit of the Pareto distribution's support. What integral with a lower limit of 1 do you mean? and are there other details needed?

Comment: It is dangerous to assume everyone uses your convention for parameters of a distribution.  Even the ubiquitous "$\mathscr N(\mu,\sigma)$" notation for Normal distributions has *three* different standard meanings (the second parameter could be the SD, the variance, or the precision).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic insight of recognising the Pareto distribution is a good way to look at this, but you are just making a small error in your reasoning about the density, which is messing things up.  Since $f(y|\mathbf{x}) = \text{Pa}(y+b^* | a^*,b^*)$ you therefore have:$^\dagger$

$$y|\mathbf{x} \sim \text{Pa}(a^*,b^*) - b^*.$$

(Note that we *subtract* $b^*$ from the Pareto variable; we don't add it.)  Consequently, you should be using a *minus* sign for the expectation computation, which gives:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[y|\textbf{x}] 
&= \mathbb{E}[r - b^* | r \sim \text{Pa}(a^*,b^*)] \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[r | r \sim \text{Pa}(a^*,b^*)] - b^* \\[6pt]
&= \frac{a^* b^*}{a^*-1} - b^* \\[6pt]
&= \frac{a^* b^*}{a^*-1} - \frac{a^* b^* - b^*}{a^*-1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{b^*}{a^*-1}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

---

$^\dagger$ This is a general rule of probability that applies when we shift the location of a random variable by a constant.  In general, if we start with a random varable $A$ with density $f_A$ then the random variable $R \equiv A+k$ has distribution function:

$$F_R(r) 
= \mathbb{P}(R \leqslant r)
= \mathbb{P}(A+k \leqslant r)
= \mathbb{P}(A \leqslant r-k)
= F_A(r-k),$$

which then gives it the density function:

$$f_R(r) = \frac{d}{dr} F_R(r) = \frac{d}{dr} F_A(r-k) = f_A(r-k).$$

As you can see, using the location shift $+k$ on the random variable translates to imposing the shift $-k$ inside the density argument.  This is because the point $R=r$ corresponds to $A=r-k$.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for, but I don't quite follow the subtraction reasoning. I would have thought that $$y|\textbf{x}\sim\text{Pa}(a^\ast,b^\ast)-b^\ast\implies f(y|\textbf{x})=\frac{a^\ast b^{\ast a^\ast}}{y^{a^\ast+1}}-b^\ast\neq\frac{a^\ast b^{\ast a^\ast}}{(y+b^\ast)^{a^\ast+1}}=\text{Pa}(y+b^\ast|a^\ast,b^\ast).$$

Comment: I have added some further detail on the location shift to show you why it works the way I say.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. Isn't the $-b^\ast$ in $y|\textbf{x}\sim\text{Pa}(a^\ast,b^\ast)-b^\ast$ a vertical shift, but the $-k$ in $f_R(r)=f_A(r-k)$ a horizontal shift? And a couple of other things I've wondered while I've stared at this, if you have the patience: should $y|\textbf{x}\sim$ be $Y|\textbf{x}\sim$? and does $f(y|\textbf{x})=\text{Pa}(y+b^\ast|a^\ast,b^\ast)$ imply that this $f$ is $f_{Y+b^\ast}$?

Comment: For purposes of this answer, I'm following the notation in your question (taken from your course notes), which does not use the upper-case convention for random variables (so $y$ is either random or fixed depending on context).  But yes, if you were going to use the upper-case notation convention then some of my notation in this answer would change.  I'm also using your own notation in the question where you use $f$ to denote the conditional density for $y$ given $\mathbf{x}$ (so $f$ is $f_Y$, not $f_{Y+b^*}$).

Comment: And how about the vertical/horizontal issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by that directional distinction.  Perhaps you could explain.

Comment: Isn't $\text{Pa}(y|a^\ast,b^\ast)$ a function value, so that a constant (here $b^\ast$) added to it moves the curve plotting the function value up or down?

Comment: I think you may be confusing yourself by equating $\text{Pa}(y|a^*,b^*)$ and $\text{Pa}(a^*,b^*)$.  The first is a density function and it behaves just as you are describing.  In the present context, the second is a reference to a *random variable* that follows the relevant Pareto distribution.  Consequently, the $-b^*$ applied to the latter is moving the *random variable* downward, not moving an argument in the density.

Comment: If you don't feel too barraged by questions, I'm finding this very useful. The distinction you mention is indeed one I haven't properly appreciated. If $\text{Pa}(a^\ast,b^\ast)$ is a random variable, does that mean that (if one had some time one one's hands) one could write $$\text{Pa}(a^\ast,b^\ast)\sim\text{Pa}(\text{Pa}(a^\ast,b^\ast)|a^\ast,b^\ast)$$? More generally I now realise I don't properly understand the relations of $X,y,z$ in $f_X(y)=\text{Some Distribution}(z|\text{some parameters})$. Is any pair of them obliged to be 'match' in some way, e.g. $z$ fixes one of $X$ or $y$?

Comment: That statement wouldn't really make sense --- remember that a random variable with a Pareto distribution has parameter values (attached to the distribution), but it does not have an argument value, since the random variable is not a density function.  Your statement appears to be trying to equate a random variable with a density at a specific point given by that random value, which does not really make sense.  With regard to your broader question, a lot of the meaning of these items depends on context and convention (and sometimes people write them differently).

Comment: Could I read "a random variable [...] does not have an argument value" as "a $Y$ does not come equipped with a $y$"?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.